# Smart table go to selected item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, html-table, smart-table

I'm using the [smart-table](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table) with pagination. Also there is a default selected item (`isSelected=true`).

What I want to achieve is that the pagination goes to the actual page of the table where the selected item is.

I tried to get the `$scope` from the pagination, to access the `selectPage()` function.But I cannot get the $scope.

`angular.element($('#pagination')).scope()`

returns the controller $scope

`angular.element($('#pagination')).isolatedScope()`

returns null

**Edit:**

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJDkitbfcuEQcEpUy94U?p=preview).

Is it possible to get the scope from a directive? I want the get the scope from [this directive](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stPagination.js)

Here's the table html:

```
<table st-table="table" st-pipe="pipeFunction" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    ...
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div id="pagination" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="8" st-template="/scripts/angular/pagination.custom.html"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: if you need an angular material one (I don't know what you need), then try this: https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable

Comment: @Iamisti the least thing i want is to replace the plugin, cause there is a lot working correctly

Comment: if you could provide an example in plunkr or codepen that would be great :)

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Sounds like all you really need is a filter for `isSelected`

Comment: @charlietfl see the plnkr in the edited post. on init i want to see the selected item (red) on the last page.

Comment: but if you have multiple selected that would appear on various pages how would that work? If all you want is to persist table state see `Persist table state in local storage` in the docs

Comment: @charlietfl it is not possible to have multiple, it is single select.

Comment: I believe you will need to extend the pagination directive to be able to set specific page. Docs explain how to extend your own.

Comment: @charlietfl i have posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I have managed it, also with the default selection.

**javascript:**

```
app.directive('stDefaultSelection', function () {
    return {
        require: 'stTable',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            selection: '=stDefaultSelection',
        },
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            scope.$watch('selection', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var selectionMode = 'single',
                    pagination = controller.tableState().pagination;

                //controller.select(newValue, selectionMode); => causes second call of function

                var rows = controller.getFilteredCollection(),
                    indexOfRow = rows.indexOf(newValue),
                    finalPage = Math.ceil(rows.length / pagination.number);

                if (indexOfRow > -1) {
                    controller.slice(finalPage * pagination.number, pagination.number);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**html:**

```
 `<table st-default-selection="selectedRow" st-table="table" st-safe-src="rowCollection"></table>`
```

Comment: personally I don't like using `st-` prefix for my own extensions so I know that if I use it again in another project it isn't something that is part of the table module. But good job creating solution

Answer (score 0):

Ah I think I found the problem.

Instead of:

```
angular.element($('#pagination')).isolatedScope()
```

Try using (without a `d`):

```
angular.element($('#pagination')).isolateScope()
```

Comment: nope is still `undefined`. I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJDkitbfcuEQcEpUy94U?p=preview)